# Running Tests in Parallel with Junit

Tags: java, testing, junit

I would like to run every method annotated with `@Test`, across multiple classes, at the same time.  For some cases, I would like to limit this, and say that only 100 total can run at any one time.  I would like methods with `@BeforeClass` annotations to be run once before any Test in a class runs, and I would like `@AfterClass` annotations to be run once after all Tests in a class run.  I would like `System.out`, `System.err`, and Exceptions to be appropriately buffered/captured rather than written out, so that they don't interleave, and I can read the final output and understand what happened.

Does this exist?  I have a large number of independent test cases, and my application is (I believe) threadsafe.  None of these tests have dependencies out of the JVM, and I want to finish them as quickly as possible, given my hardware.

If this doesn't exist, is there a concrete reason why not?  How much time is lost by junit users worldwide because this isn't easy?  Can I build it into Junit?  In my mind, this should be as simple as a single flag, and it "just works".

Answer (score 22):

You can accomplish this with JUnit's `ParallelComputer` (note it's still considered experimental).  It's a pretty simple implementation which is backed by the java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService API.
  If you're curious how it works, [check out the source](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/ParallelComputer.java).

Basically you call `JUnitCore.runClasses(Computer, Classes ...)` and pass in a `ParallelComputer` object for the first argument.

Example usage:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.ParallelComputer;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class ParallelComputerExample {

    @Test
    public void runAllTests() {
        Class<?>[] classes = { ParallelTest1.class, ParallelTest2.class };

        // ParallelComputer(true,true) will run all classes and methods 
        // in parallel.  (First arg for classes, second arg for methods)
        JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, true), classes);
    }

    public static class ParallelTest1 {
        @Test
        public void test1a() {
            lookBusy(3000);
        }

        @Test
        public void test1b() {
            lookBusy(3000);
        }
    }

    public static class ParallelTest2 {
        @Test
        public void test2a() {
            lookBusy(3000);
        }

        @Test
        public void test2b() {
            lookBusy(3000);
        }
    }

    public static void lookBusy(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will run in 3 seconds because all methods and classes are ran in parallel.

This will run in 6s (because all classes are in parallel).
`JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, false), classes);`

This will also run in 6s (because all methods are in parallel).
`JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(false, true), classes);`

Comment: You should not call JUnitCore.runClasses() from a @Test. This will mess up the test reports. See: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1102

The real solution to run test in parallel is to extend the Runner or the Suite

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-run-tests-in-parallel/

Answer (score 9):

Yes, You can.

If you are using maven. You can take help of

**maven-surefire-plugin**

In Spring,

You can check this [Link](http://incodewetrustinc.blogspot.in/2009/07/run-your-junit-tests-in-parallel-with.html)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>5</threadCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Solution 2: Junit4 provides parallel feature using **ParallelComputer**

Comment: How do I make sure tests are running in parallel? I don't see any reduction in execution time of test cases

Answer (score 5):

[JUnit Toolbox](https://github.com/michaeltamm/junit-toolbox) provides JUnit runners for parallel execution of tests.

In order to not intermix output to `System.err` and `System.out` you have to start tests in separate JVMs, because `System.err` and `System.out` are global.

Comment: This IntelliJ plugin is built on top of JUnit Toolbox: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12959-junit4-parallel-runner.